# Redirect subdomain to the user profile

Tags: subdomain, apache2, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

I want to redirect all subdomains to the user profile , eg:

redirect this URL : 
`http://alexusername.example.com`

To : 
`http://alexusername.example.com`

But showing the content of :
`http://example.com/user.php?q=alexusername`

I mean that I want to show the content of the `http://example.com/user.php?q=alexusername` without changing the URL in the browser I want it to still `http://alexusername.example.com`

I have tried this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.blackhawk.site$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).blackhawk.site [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blackhawk.site/user.php?q=%2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You don't use rewrite here, you need to make a virtual host that maps the subdomain to the script.

Comment: How to do that please ?

Comment: Google for "apache virtual host setup" and follow guide.

Comment: I think this require some Apache permissions but I have a domain on a hosting server !

Comment: Then you need to set up hosting yourself on a place where you can modify Apache configuration.